# Pivot a pandas dataframe with duplicate index values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, pivot-table

I have a dataframe like this:

```
ID      Status     Status_date
1       Active     10/9/2010
1       Closed     12/10/2010
2       Open       2/2/2013
3       Open       12/02/2012
3       Active     2/3/2013
4       Closed     3/3/2009
```

I want to pivot it to look like this:

```
ID   Status  Status_date  Status  Status_date  Status  Status_date
1    NaN     NaN          Active  10/9/2010    Closed  12/10/2010
2    Open    2/2/2013     NaN     NaN          NaN     NaN
3    Open    12/2/2012    Active  2/3/2013     NaN     NaN
4    NaN     NaN          NaN     NaN          Closed  NaN
```

How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you wanted your data that way, but here it goes:

```
new_df = (df.pivot('ID','Status',['Status','Status_date'])
   .sort_index(level=(1,0), axis=1)
)
new_df.columns = [x for x,_ in new_df.columns]
```

Output:

```
    Status Status_date  Status Status_date Status Status_date
ID                                                           
1   Active   10/9/2010  Closed  12/10/2010    NaN         NaN
2      NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN   Open    2/2/2013
3   Active    2/3/2013     NaN         NaN   Open  12/02/2012
4      NaN         NaN  Closed    3/3/2009    NaN         NaN
```

Note that duplicated column names in Pandas are generally discouraged unless you really know what you are doing

Comment: I still get the error: ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Comment: @Soham looks like you got multiple same status per ID, for example 2 `Open`'s for ID `1`. This case does not show in your sample data. You need to decide what to do with those first.